# Looping program when I try to close it. How do I fix this infinite loop?

Tags: java, string, loops, infinite-loop

This program is supposed to take in input from the user, put it into a text file, and then be able to pull info if needed later on (not yet implemented).  The program open and take in values and save them, but when I go to close the program, a new window appears, and this repeats.  Any help on how to stop this? It might just be a break missing somewhere, but I can't fix it for the life of me.

```
public class FirstTr {

final private static int MAX_RECORD_NUMBER = 71;
final private static int MAX_PLAYER_NUMBER = 99;
final private static char PLAYER_NAME = 26;
final private static char TEAM_NAME = 26;
final private static int SKILL_LEVEL = 5;
final private static int DRAFT_DATE = 9;
final private static int RECORD_LENGTH = 16;
final private static int PLAYER_ID = 20;
final private static int ID_Length = 5;


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {


    File loc = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Exc2.1.txt");
    RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(loc, "rw");
    String id1 = "";
    String id2 = "";
    String id3 = "";
    String id4 = "";
    String id = "";
    String Description = "";
    int recLocation = 0;
    String cmd = "Start";
    String where = "0";




    cmd= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Please type in a command : new, old or exit");

    if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")== 0){
        store.close();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    while (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")!= 0){

        if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("new") == 0){
            //Ask user for ID 1-20, read ID
            try{
                id1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ID(1-20):");
                recLocation= Integer.parseInt(id1);
                assert Integer.MAX_VALUE == PLAYER_ID;

                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The ID IS "+ id1);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY THIS IS NOT AN INTEGER PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

            }
            try{
                //Ask user for player name, read name
                id2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a players name");
                assert id.length()== PLAYER_NAME;
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The players name is " + id2 + " press enter to continue");
                store.writeUTF(id2); 
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY SOMETHING WENT WRONG PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

            }
            try{
                //ask for player team name, read team name
                id3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a players team name");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The players team name is " + id3 + ", press enter to continue");
                assert id.length()== TEAM_NAME;
                store.writeUTF(id3);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SOMETHING WENT WRONG PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

            }

            //enter player skill level, read skill level(0-99)
            try{    
                id4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a players skill level (0-99)");
                recLocation = Integer.parseInt(id4);
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The players skill level " + id4 + " press enter to continue");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY THIS IS NOT AN INTEGER PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

            }
            //enter player skill level, read skill level
            try{    
                id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter todays Date");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Today is " + id + " press enter to continue");
                assert id.length()== DRAFT_DATE;
                store.writeUTF(id);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY THIS IS NOT AN INTEGER PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");
                continue;
            }
            //convert ID and skill level to string(char-5)


        }



        //if command is old, ask for ID and read Id, then use ID to retrieve record, display the record formatted for readability


        if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("old") == 0) {
            try{
                where = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter player:");
                recLocation = Integer.parseInt(where);
                store.seek((PLAYER_ID) * (recLocation-1));
                Description = store.readUTF();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Description);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry there is no player try again");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading input for `cmd` one time, and then it is never re-assigned. So, that first `while` loop is going to loop forever if its condition (`cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")!= 0`) is true in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while loop` is the culprit. The loop literally keeps going because there is nothing that is changing the condition.

if you were to make a way to change this condition `(cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")!= 0)` to true somewhere within your script, your script will terminate the way you wanted it to!

**NOTE:** you are not assigning the word `"exit"` to a command! Maybe making a command for that will make the script do what you want!

**EDIT:** Try changing `"end"` to `"exit"` within these snippets here!

```
if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")== 0){
        store.close();
        System.exit(0);

while (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")!= 0)
```

**EDIT2**: By adding the above if statement to the bottom of your while loop, it should exit!

```
while (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("exit")!= 0){

    if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("new") == 0){
        //Ask user for ID 1-20, read ID
        try{
            id1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ID(1-20):");
            recLocation= Integer.parseInt(id1);
            assert Integer.MAX_VALUE == PLAYER_ID;

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The ID IS "+ id1);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY THIS IS NOT AN INTEGER PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

        }
        try{
            //Ask user for player name, read name
            id2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a players name");
            assert id.length()== PLAYER_NAME;
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The players name is " + id2 + " press enter to continue");
            store.writeUTF(id2); 
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY SOMETHING WENT WRONG PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

        }
        try{
            //ask for player team name, read team name
            id3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a players team name");
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The players team name is " + id3 + ", press enter to continue");
            assert id.length()== TEAM_NAME;
            store.writeUTF(id3);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SOMETHING WENT WRONG PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

        }

        //enter player skill level, read skill level(0-99)
        try{    
            id4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a players skill level (0-99)");
            recLocation = Integer.parseInt(id4);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The players skill level " + id4 + " press enter to continue");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY THIS IS NOT AN INTEGER PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");

        }
        //enter player skill level, read skill level
        try{    
            id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter todays Date");
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Today is " + id + " press enter to continue");
            assert id.length()== DRAFT_DATE;
            store.writeUTF(id);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SORRY THIS IS NOT AN INTEGER PLEASE PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");
            continue;
        }
        //convert ID and skill level to string(char-5)


    }



    //if command is old, ask for ID and read Id, then use ID to retrieve record, display the record formatted for readability


    if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("old") == 0) {
        try{
            where = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter player:");
            recLocation = Integer.parseInt(where);
            store.seek((PLAYER_ID) * (recLocation-1));
            Description = store.readUTF();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Description);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry there is no player try again");
            continue;
        }

    if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("exit")== 0){
            store.close();
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried that, but does not change anything.  I believe I need to change the conditions for the while and/or if, but not sure what to change it to.